# How to take different inputs in a struct array

Tags: arrays, c, function, input, struct

I'm currently trying to do project that consists of creating a program that helps to manage a fleet of eletric vehicles. In this program, the fleet can only have a maximum of 10 vehicles. These vehicles have data that the user will write (vehicle identification, available battery, registration date, etc). So (in my view), the ideal was to create a structure for each vehicle, therefore making a array of 10 for that struct.
One of the functionalities was something I described earlier: "Register new vehicle" - the user will input some data in order to regist a new vehicle. I have been trying to solve a problem for a good 2 day which is how to input the different vehicles identification numbers in the vectors.

This is some of the code I have:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    void RegisterNewVehicle();
    void ChooseSlot();

    // Struct
struct Vehicle
    {
        int ON;
        char VehicleID[9];
    }Vehicle[10];



    // Choose slot menu
    void ChooseSlot()
    {

int Slot;

do{
printf("Choose a slot to register the car:\n\n"
        "1.  <Empty>\n"
        "2.  <Empty>\n"
        // (...)
        "10. <Empty>\n"
        "\n0.  Go Back\n");
scanf(" %d", &Slot);

// What happens based on the user choice
switch(Slot){
    case 1:                                         // Chooses 1
        if(Vehicle[0].ON==1)             // If slot not empty (var ON = 1)
           {
               system("cls");
               printf("Slot taken. Choose another one.\n");
           }
        else                                        // If slot empty (var ON = 0 will be = 1)
        {Vehicle[0].ON = 1;  
        RegisterNewVehicle();}
        break;

    case 2:                                       // Chooses 2
        if(Vehicle[1].ON==1) 
           {
               system("cls");
               printf("Slot taken. Choose another one.\n");
           }
        else
       {Vehicle[1].ON=1;
       RegisterNewVehicle();}
        break;


    // Menu to Register the vehicle data
    void RegisterNewVehicle()
    {
    printf("\tPlease input the following data:");

    // Register vehicle ID
    printf("\nVehicle ID: ");
    scanf(" %s", Vehicle[0].VehicleID); // Problem
```

With the function
`ChooseSlot();`
I want the user to choose to register the vehicle in one of the existing slots if empty, and then forwarded to the menu `RegisterNewVehicle()`
In this menu, the user will enter the different type of data the vehicle has that he wants to register (vehicle identification, available battery, registration date, etc). My problem, as I said earlier, is in the `scanf(" %s", Vehicle[0].VehicleID);`
Since regardless of the option the user chooses in the choose slot function, the array will always be the same, so it will be rewritten.
The only solution I can think of is to redirect each of the options in the slots list to a different function, and work each car individually from there. The problem is that as there are 10 cars, and there is a lot of data in the cars to input in addition to other features that are not here, the code would be unnecessarily huge, not to mention the dynamic memory that would be used.
As you can see, I have almost no programming experience. I glady accept any suggestions, ideas, criticisms, etc.

Comment: What is wrong with `scanf(" %s", Vehicle[slot].VehicleID);`? Pass `slot` to the `RegisterNewVehicle` function.

Comment: But more fundamentally it is unusual to ask a user for the slot. Would a real registration office ask you which slot to use for your own data? No, the more correct approach is for the system itself to search the "database" (arrray in this case) for an empty slot.

Comment: Avoid buffer overruns `scanf(" %s", Vehicle[0].VehicleID)` --> `scanf("%8s", Vehicle[0].VehicleID)` and check the return value.  BTW, what is sample input?.  Note: space in `" %s"` serves no purpose.